# Spring Security Oauth2 Authentication for Javascript WebApp

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm currently developing a React WebApp with a Spring Boot REST API in the backend. I want to use OAuth2 to secure the API (and to improve my knowledge). I have however some questions regarding the correct authentication flow to use.

Since the frontend is using JavaScript I should not use flows that require a client secret.

The only flow that does not require a client secret in Spring is the Implicit Flow. With this flow however, Spring does not support refresh tokens. That means that after some time the user would get automatically logged out and needs to authorize the WebApp again.

Another option I saw was creating a client without a secret and then use the Authorization Code flow. But I have some doubts if this is the right way to go.

So my question basically: Which is the best OAuth2 flow to use with a Javascript frontend, when I don't want the user to be logged out after some time?

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(Encoders.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-server-rest-api";
    private static final String SECURED_READ_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('read')";
    private static final String SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('write')";
    private static final String SECURED_PATTERN = "/api/**";

    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
            .tokenServices(tokenServices)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher(SECURED_PATTERN).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

**OAuth2Config**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence.properties"})
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource("mykeys.jks"),
                "mypass".toCharArray());

        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("mykeys"));
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients().tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Implicit flow` is meant for JavaScript implementations according to the [OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2)

Refresh tokens are not supported with the Implicit flow. The spring implementation is following the [Oauth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2).

In case of a Javascript client implementations, tokens are stored on the client. When using refresh tokens, the refresh token needs to be persisted on the client in order to obtain a new access token in the future. If this is the case, you might as wel issue a long(er) lasting access token instead of a refresh token. When working client side, there is no advantage in using refresh token.